# Suspicious GET request parameter list?

Tags: web-application, injection

Is there a public list of common suspicious GET request parameter ?
I mean - SQLi, Command Injection, Admin access   etc.
I am interested in such list, to be used to detect suspicious GET request in SIEM(arcsight)

Any idea, reference -  will be welcome.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Too many for a list to be useful. You should work on white-listing instead.

Comment: Any GET request that isn't part of your expected GET request in accordance with the web application design flow is suspicious. Like Question Overflow said, there are too many to list.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, if you can whitelist instead of blacklisting you can save a lot of efforts.

You can get a list from [ModSecurity](https://www.modsecurity.org),  it is not simple to parse on your own but this is probably the most comprehensive you will get publicly.